# Converting between correlation and effect size (Cohen's d)

Tags: effect-size, pearson-r, cohens-d

Several sources ([here](https://www.uccs.edu/lbecker/effect-size) [here](https://trendingsideways.com/the-cohens-d-formula) [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15749/how-to-report-effect-size-measures-r-and-r-squared-and-what-is-a-non-technical-e)) claim that there is a relation between Cohen's d and Pearson's r if the data is paired (bivariate). This strikes me as odd since, for example, evaluating a "before and after" scenario, one could end up with "after" values being the same as "before". This would yield a Cohen's d = 0 (the mean did not change) but Pearson's r = 1 (correlation of x = y). The result in this case is completely turned around.

I'd appreciate if someone would give an explanation why this relation makes sense. Worked-out examples would also be welcome.

Comment: See also this question on [converting r to d with unequal groups](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/526789/convert-correlation-r-to-cohens-d-unequal-groups-of-known-size)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relationship described for Cohen's *d* and Pearson's *r* isn't for paired data.  It's for unpaired data. For *r*, one variable is the two groups and the other is measurement variable.  I've attached a plot to illustrate this, and some R code that works through an example.  As is, I think it only works if the two samples have equal numbers of observations.

Note that for the simplest statement of this relationship, [`d = 2*r / sqrt(1 - r^2)`](https://trendingsideways.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/r-to-cohens-d.png), that the formula for Cohen's d needs to use *n* in the denominator for the pooled standard deviation and not *n - 2*, as is common.  Also note that I think the formulas presented work only with equal sample sizes. The webpages provided don't seem to address these assumptions.

[image]

```
### At the time of writing,
###  the following code will run on https://rdrr.io/snippets/

if(!require(lsr)){install.packages("lsr")}
library(lsr)

Y = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
Group = rep(c("A","B"), 1, each=10)
Group.n = as.numeric(factor(Group))

cohensD(Y ~ Group, method="raw")

   ### Note that this method uses n in the denominator,
   ###  not n-2, as is more usual.

   ### [1] 0.6963106

r = cor(Y, Group.n)
r

   ### [1] 0.328798

d =  2*r/sqrt(1-r^2)
d

   ### [1] 0.6963106


if(!require(ggplot2)){install.packages("ggplot2")}
library(ggplot2)

qplot(Group.n, Y)
```

Comment: [Lakens, 2013, Calculating and reporting effect sizes..., Front. Psychol.](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fpsyg.2013.00863/full) has the correct formula for converting Cohen's d <sub>s</sub> (the more common formula with the *n-2*): `r.Lakens = CohenDs / sqrt(CohenDs^2 + (N^2 - 2*N)/(n1*n2))`

Comment: It appears Lakens' formula also works with unequal sample sizes.